# JSON Schema 4 validate exactly one definition

Tags: aws-api-gateway, jsonschema

I would my HTTP request body will accept something like:

```
{
    "grant_type": "refresh_token", // "refresh_token" or "password"
    "client_id": "my-client",      // NEVER CHANGE
    "refresh_token": "XXX"
}
```

or

```
{
    "grant_type": "password",   // "refresh_token" or "password"
    "client_id": "my-client",   // NEVER CHANGE
    "username": "XXX",
    "password": "XXX",
}
```

As you can see the format change, based on `grant_type`. So I defined this schema:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "username_and_password": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "grant_type": { "type": "string", "enum": ["password"] },
            "client_id": { "type": "string", "enum": ["my-client"] },
            "username": { "type": "string" },
            "password": { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": ["grant_type", "client_id", "username", "password" ]
    },
    "refresh_token": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "grant_type": { "type": "string", "enum": ["refresh_token"] },
            "client_id": { "type": "string", "enum": ["my-client"] },
            "refresh_token": { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": [ "grant_type", "client_id", "refresh_token" ]
    }
  },

  "oneOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/username_and_password" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/refresh_token" }
  ],

  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I use this as model of API Gateway but it denies everything I send. Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

`additionalProperties` being false is your problem.

It cannot "see through" `oneOf` or `$ref` references.

> If "additionalProperties" has boolean value false...
>
> In this case, validation of the instance depends on the property
> set    of "properties" and "patternProperties".

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.4.4.4

There's a little more explanantion of how this works, and we clarified it for draft-5 onwards, but essentially...

`additionalProperties` is applicable to all properties which are not defined in `properties` in the same schema object level as `additionalProperties`.

Because your schema only has `additionalProperties` and no `properties` defined, ALL properties cause validation to fail.

You can get round this by defining the properties, where the value of each are empty schemas. In draft-5 onwards, you can use `true` as the value, because `true` and `false` are valid "schemas".